# Why does this statement not work appropriately? Ternary operation & classcastexception

Tags: java, json, ternary-operator, classcastexception

I have a `JSONObject` which I am parsing and sometimes some of the data is null.

In this case, ReportId = null..so, I tried to use a ternary operator to prevent the `ClassCastException`, however, it doesn't work.

The specific object throwing the error has `"ReportId":null`....can I not do this?

Line:

```
item.setReportId((jsonObj.get("ReportId") != null || jsonObj.get("ReportId") != "null") ? (Integer)jsonObj.get("ReportId") : 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a look at the documentation for [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html), it appears to have a number of convenience methods. For example:

```
item.setReportId( (!jsonObj.isNull("ReportId")) ? jsonObj.getInt("ReportId") : 0);
```

Comment: The JSON Object returns an `Object`, not a `String`, for ReportId.
See here: `The method valueOf(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (Object)`

Comment: @Bringer, Where did you use ternary operator?

Comment: @Sunil You can see it in my last code block. I separated it onto multiple lines.

Comment: The statement you originally posted doesn't make any difference. I still get the `ClassCastException`. Let me check out the convenience method you added.

Comment: @DoctorOreo In that case I will remove the start of my answer as it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Try with following condition, 
If there is valid numeric reportid in json then set the report id otherwise set 0 as report id

```
 try{
            reportId = (jsonObj.get("ReportId") != null) ? Integer.parseInt((String)jsonObj.get("ReportId")) : 0;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            reportId = 0;
        }

        item.setReportId(reportId);
```

Comment: The use of `||` is incorrect here - the correct negation of `A || B` is `!A && !B`.

Comment: Ok I will re-write the condition